# CI Bonfire: Cannot call methods on Model

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to BF. I am learning BF by following the tutorial here, but I cant figure out why it keep prompt me error message as below:

> *Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on a non-object in ...*

Here is the code:

```
class Content extends Admin_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    Template::set('toolbar_title', 'Manage Your Blog');
}

public function index(){
    $posts = $this->post_model->where('deleted', 0)->find_all();
    Template::set('posts', $posts);
    Template::render();
}
}
```

Can someone guide me on this? Thanks

Comment: Not really sure how BF works, but I think you miss a line `$this->load->model('post_model');`. You have to load the model, before you use it. See if it works.

Comment: Tried, but now it prompt another error as below:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)..
Can you guide me on this? It should be the same as CI

Answer (score 1):

bborisovs is right, you need to load the model in the constructor, before you can use the obgject:

$this->load->model('post_model', null, true);

Also make sure your model exists.